# vector and push_back()

Tags: c++, vector, push-back, stdmove

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class my {
  public:
    my() {
      counter++;
      std::cout << "class constructor" << counter << " \n";}

    ~my() {
      std::cout << "class destructor" << counter << " \n";
      counter--;
    }
  
    static inline int counter = 0;
};

int main()
{
    my v1;
    std::vector<my> my_vec;

    my * p = new my();
    my_vec.push_back(std::move(*p));
    my_vec.push_back(std::move(v1));
}
```

simply example, however I do not understand what I am doing wrong, in result I get 2 extra destructor called than I expect (expect 2). Could some one explain it?

results:

```
class constructor1
class constructor2
class destructor2
class destructor1
class destructor0
class destructor-1
```

Comment: A moved-from instance must still be destroyed.

Comment: @underscore_d but where is the 4th output coming from ? I count 4 instances out of which only 3 get destroyed

Comment: You're also not tracking move construction, so the counter isn't modified there, but is being modified by the destruction of remnants of said-same. Its much easier to see where things seem to go south by remembering the counter per object at construction rather than just reporting it. An "id" if you will. It will also force you to realize a move-from object should clear that id to note it no longer refers to a concrete construction (but still needs destruction).

Comment: emplace_back might give a different result than push_back, because it might not make the copy that push_back will.

Comment: Here's a version of your code https://godbolt.org/z/ozxofc. I instrumented the copy constructor and I deleted `p`. Everything looks in order

Comment: And here's a version with the move constructor instrumented as well https://godbolt.org/z/oTh9fW

Comment: You're only tracking calls of one constructor.   There are other constructors that will be implicitly supplied by the compiler, and which you are not tracking.

Answer (score 3):

Analyzing the program step-by-step:

`my v1;`

One Instance is created, constructor is called.

`my * p = new my();`

Another instance is created, constructor is called.

```
my_vec.push_back(std::move(*p));
```

A *copy* of the second instance is inserted into the vector; the implicitly defined move-constructor is called (which just copies; no output is printed).

```
my_vec.push_back(std::move(v1));
```

The vector allocates new storage for 2 instances, *copies* the previously stored instance into the new storage (invoking the implicitly defined move-constructor, which just does copying, still no output for this), and invokes the destructor for the instance in the old storage (so first destructor output is printed).

Then, the vector goes out of scope, so its two contained elements get destroyed (so, 2 destructor calls). Then, `v1` goes out of scope, printing the 4th destructor call. The instance `p` is leaked, i.e. never destroyed (memory leak).

Answer (score 1):

Please see inline ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class my {
  public:
    my() {
      counter++;
      std::cout << "class constructor" << counter << " \n";
      std::cout << "Object Address : " << this << std::endl;
    }


    ~my() {
      std::cout << "class destructor" << counter << " \n";
      std::cout << "Object Address : " << this << std::endl;
      counter--;
    }

    static inline int counter = 0;
};

int main()
{
    my v1;     /* 1. Object on stack (constructor called) */
    std::vector<my> my_vec;

    my * p = new my();   /* 2. Object created on heap (constructor called) */
    my_vec.push_back(std::move(*p));
    my_vec.push_back(std::move(v1));
}
```

Output is:

```
class constructor 1 Address : 0x7ffee1488760
class constructor 2 Address : 0x7f9f47400350
class destructor 2 Address : 0x7f9f474026e0
class destructor 1 Address : 0x7f9f474026f1
class destructor 0 Address : 0x7f9f474026f0
class destructor -1 Address : 0x7ffee1488760
```

Object on the stack called destructor as soon as it goes out of the scope i.e. Scope of the object on stack is limited to the code block. In this case block end when main exits.

But the object on heap (`new`) is a potential leak, had this being inside while loop would have consumed memory and eventually crashed. For each `new` you need to explicitly called `delete`, which means you have to call its destructor. Thanks to `stack` it does that for us but not `heap`, and c++ also doesn't have garbage collector.

`std::move` is a copy operation and hence no constructor is called. details [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move).

Comment: @Deore Thank you.
I have seen documentation of std::move but what actually means magic: " allowing the efficient transfer of resources from t to another object". I missunderstand std::move, now I understand more, however do you know "low level examples" of moving resources? could you recommend something?